# Circumscribed circle of compact set.

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

I was looking at an article about the "Four-vertex theorem", I saw this and got troubled about proving what it says.

---

Let $E$ be a fixed nonempty compact set in the plane. Among all circles $C$ that enclose $E$ **there is a unique smallest one**, the circumscribed circle, as in the picture.
[image]

What can $C\cap E$ look like?

1. $C\cap E\neq \varnothing$, otherwise $C$ could be made smaller and still enclose $E$.
2. $C\cap E$ cannot lie in an open semi-circle. Otherwise we could shift $C$ a bit, without changing its size so that the new $C$ encloses $E$ but does not meet it. But this would contradict 1.
3. Thus $C\cap E$ has at least two points, and if only these, then they must be antipodal. This happens when $E$ is an ellipse.

---

Intuitively these propositions seem true, but I haven't been able to devise a proof for some, and complete it for some other:

- Among all circles $C$ that enclose $E$ **there is a unique smallest one**, the circumscribed circle.

Here I think I don't need to use totally the compact property, and only need bounded. As $E$ is bounded there is a ball $B$ such that $E\subseteq B$. I think I must show there is some ball contained in all these balls, but I don't know how to complete this part.

Perhaps I could build a decreasing sequence of the radii of these balls, bounded below, and check its convergence.

Or perhaps, make a sequence of nested closed balls bounding $E$ and check its intersection. But I don't see how to build that sequence, and which center to use.

- $C\cap E\neq \varnothing$, otherwise $C$ could be made smaller and still enclose $E$.

I don't see it clearly how to prove that in that case $C$ could be made smaller.
Here I think I need both closed and bounded (So compact). Perhaps using the distance between the set and the circle, and using that to build a smaller circle. Is this correct (If it is, I will keep thinking this)?

- $C\cap E$ cannot lie in an open semi-circle. Otherwise we could shift $C$ a bit, without changing its size so that the new $C$ encloses $E$ but does not meet it. But this would contradict 1.

I don't really understand this part, what does it mean to shift $C$ so that it still encloses.

---

I also have the doubt about what is the unique smallest circle which encloses an arbitrary  quadrilateral. Is this really true?

Comment: I've seen these three propositions when $E$ is finite: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem.

Comment: Oh, that seems very intersting. But from what I see that article will need $E$ possibly infinite (Even uncountable)...

Comment: But that solves the particular case of my last question, about the smallest circle enclosing an arbitrary quadrilateral (Since balls are convex). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your decreasing sequence of balls will work to show the existance of a unique "local minimum" circle. But proving it is the global minimum would be difficult with that argument, I think.

Your idea on $C \cap E \ne \emptyset$ is correct. Since both sets are compact, there is a positive distance between them ($d(x,y) : C \times E \to \Bbb R$ is a continuous function on a compact set, and so must have a compact image).

As for the final point, they are saying that if all the intersections occur on one side of $C$ only (breaking $C$ into two half-circles), then there is some positive distance between the other half-circle and $E$, so if you move $C$ in the direction that brings that side closer to $E$ and the other side away, there is a little room to do so without intersecting $E$ on that side. Meanwhile the side that had been intersecting $E$ moves away, and so stops intersecting $E$.

Comment: Yes, now I think that by that method I should move the center to make it work. Well, thanks!